# QinQ does not work with L2VPN (VSI and MPLS L2VC - Switch Huawei)

Tags: vlan, mpls, huawei, qinq, l2vpn

Currently, I am trying to configure a network to transport multiple VLANs for a client who has points in different locations (Side A and Side B). My idea was to use QinQ for this. The network topology is represented in the figure below:
[image]

The configuration of switches A and B is as follows:

Switch A

```
#
interface XGigabitEthernet0/0/44
 description Clientx - Side A
 port link-type hybrid
 qinq vlan-translation enable
 port hybrid tagged vlan 668
 port hybrid untagged vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 100 stack-vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 200 stack-vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 499 stack-vlan 667
#

#
interface Vlanif667
 l2 binding vsi clientex
#
```

Switch B

```
#
interface XGigabitEthernet0/0/24
 description ClientX - Side B
 port link-type hybrid
 qinq vlan-translation enable
 port hybrid tagged vlan 668
 port hybrid untagged vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 100 stack-vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 200 stack-vlan 667
 port vlan-stacking vlan 499 stack-vlan 667
#

#
interface Vlanif667
 l2 binding vsi clientex
#
```

The VSI is active because there is an MPLS session established between switch A and switch B. However, when I try to ping from switch A to B or vice-versa, using the /30 IP addresses added to VLANs 100, 200, and 499, there is no communication. I tried changing from VSI to MPLS L2VC, but without success. Communication only works when I pass the VLAN 667 directly to the interfaces of Switch A, X and B (without using MPLS transport). Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Notes:

- I cannot maintain the configuration by passing the VLANs on the interfaces because the actual topology is larger than this example, and some interfaces have disabled port switches.
- I cannot choose to configure VSI directly on the physical interfaces and remove QinQ because I need to pass VLAN 668 for management of the customer equipment connected to Switch A.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use following config:

```
interface XGigabitEthernet0/0/44
 description Clientx - Side A
 port link-type hybrid
 qinq vlan-translation enable
 port hybrid tagged vlan 668

interface XGigabitEthernet0/0/44.667
qinq stacking vid 100  pe-vid 667
qinq stacking vid 200  pe-vid 667
qinq stacking vid 499  pe-vid 667
l2 binding vsi clientex
```